# How to change css display none or block with button click

Tags: jquery, html, css

Click the button when the display property changes.

example,
button class = "1" click results - the first-img class display: block,
The second-img class display: none, the third-img class display: none.

button class = "2" click results - the first-img class display: none,
The second-img class display: block, the third-img class display: none.

button class = "3" click results - the first-img class display: none,
The second-img class display: none, the third-img class display: block.

codepen = http://codepen.io/soso77/pen/bwkYZX

```css
ol,
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
}
.slider {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 980px;
}
img.first-img,
img.second-img,
img.third-img {
  max-height: 625px;
  display: block;
}
img.second-img,
img.third-img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-1st" class="first-img" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-2nd" class="second-img" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-3er" class="third-img" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-1st" class="first-img" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-2nd" class="second-img" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-3er" class="third-img" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-1st" class="first-img" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-2nd" class="second-img" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-3er" class="third-img" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-1st" class="first-img" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-2nd" class="second-img" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-3er" class="third-img" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: yea.. i think you need js for this one. Probably the easiest way is to have a class image with display:none; and a class selected with display block. Then on click using js you rremove the selected class for all the elements with class image and add the selected class to the desired image based on the button you clicked. PS: where are the buttons?

Comment: @Lidaranis Button below to create a class Ul. Can I use Jquery?
If Jquery if available, can you tell me? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the class number using `attribute class` and the use `nth-child()` to select the image. Here is my short answer:

```
   $('button').click( function (){
        var number = $(this).attr('class');
        $('ul li img').css('display', 'none');
      $('ul li img:nth-child('+number+')').css('display', 'block');
    })
```

See the snippet below for the question requirements:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var X = jQuery.noConflict();

var realSlider= X("ul#bxslider").bxSlider({
      speed:1000,
      pager:false,
      nextText:'',
      prevText:'',
      infiniteLoop:false,
      hideControlOnEnd:true,
      onSlideBefore:function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
        changeRealThumb(realThumbSlider,newIndex);

      }

    });

    var realThumbSlider=X("ul#bxslider-pager").bxSlider({
      minSlides: 4,
      maxSlides: 4,
      slideWidth: 235,
      slideMargin: 9,
      moveSlides: 1,
      pager:false,
      speed:1000,
      infiniteLoop:false,
      hideControlOnEnd:true,
      nextText:'<span></span>',
      prevText:'<span></span>',
      onSlideBefore:function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
        /*X("#sliderThumbReal ul .active").removeClass("active");
        $slideElement.addClass("active"); */

      }
    });

    linkRealSliders(realSlider,realThumbSlider);

    if(X("#bxslider-pager li").length<4){
      X("#bxslider-pager .bx-next").hide();
    }

// sincronizza sliders realizzazioni
function linkRealSliders(bigS,thumbS){

  X("ul#bxslider-pager").on("click","a",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var newIndex=X(this).parent().attr("data-slideIndex");
        bigS.goToSlide(newIndex);
  });
}

//slider!=$thumbSlider. slider is the realslider
function changeRealThumb(slider,newIndex){

  var $thumbS=X("#bxslider-pager");
  $thumbS.find('.active').removeClass("active");
  $thumbS.find('li[data-slideIndex="'+newIndex+'"]').addClass("active");

  if(slider.getSlideCount()-newIndex>=3)slider.goToSlide(newIndex);
  else slider.goToSlide(slider.getSlideCount()-3);

}

 
});
   $('button').click( function (){
        var number = $(this).attr('class');
        $('ul li img').css('display', 'none');
      $('ul li img:nth-child('+number+')').css('display', 'block');
    })
```

```css
ol, ul, li {
    list-style: none;
}

.slider {float: left;position: relative;width: 980px;}

img.first-img,img.second-img,img.third-img {
    max-height: 625px;
    display: block;
}

img.second-img,img.third-img {
    display: none;
}

.ori-image-button {position: absolute !important;top:0;left:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ori-image-button">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
  <div class="ori-image-button">
  
  
<button class="1">Class 1 </button>
<button class="2">Class 2 </button>
<button class="3">Class 3 </button>
</div>

-    <ul id="bxslider">
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-1st" class="first-img" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-2nd" class="second-img" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-3rd" class="third-img" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-1st" class="first-img" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-2nd" class="second-img" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-3rd" class="third-img" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-1st" class="first-img" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-2nd" class="second-img" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-3rd" class="third-img" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-1st" class="first-img" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-2nd" class="second-img" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-3rd" class="third-img" />
        </li>
    </ul>

<ul id="bxslider-pager">
  <li data-slideIndex="1"><a href=""><img class="first" src="http://placehold.it/235x150/?text=image-1st" alt="thumb-img" width="235" height="150"></a>
  <li data-slideIndex="2"><a href=""><img class="first" src="http://placehold.it/235x150/?text=image-2st" alt="thumb-img" width="235" height="150"></a>
  <li data-slideIndex="3"><a href=""><img class="first" src="http://placehold.it/235x150/?text=image-3rd" alt="thumb-img" width="235" height="150"></a>
  <li data-slideIndex="4"><a href=""><img class="first" src="http://placehold.it/235x150/?text=image-4th" alt="thumb-img" width="235" height="150"></a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you.What should I do when this is the case?
http://codepen.io/soso77/pen/bwkYZX

Comment: @sosori I should works without changing the script. Just updated the html. See the update above. Please let me know if this is the answer you were looking for

Comment: Sorry :`-(  I'm finally trying to use an bxslider. Please click here.
http://codepen.io/soso77/pen/bwkYZX

Comment: @sosori It should works without changing the script. you just forget to import the jquery. Just updated the html. See the update above. Please let me know if this is the answer you were looking for

Comment: @sosori and you put my script inside a function. Don't do that because it will not fire. I put it outside the function. Please let me know if this is the answer you were looking for

Comment: The best answer! Thank you.!

Comment: actually the first version of this answer was much better and neat, now it is too tied to a specific troubleshooting session

Comment: @TSR There are additional questions.One button, two buttons, three buttons, try to stop by the rolling of the image that contains each.Images try to stop rolling hover above.Do you have ever accidentally tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <button data-notation="true" class="1">Class 1 </button>
<button data-notation="true" class="2">Class 2 </button>
<button data-notation="true" class="3">Class 3 </button>



 <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-1st" class="first-img" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-2nd" class="second-img" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-3rd" class="third-img" />
        </li>
    </ul>
```

in the js section:

```
$(".button[data-notation=true]").on("click",function(){
    var index = parseInt($(this).attr("class"));
    $("ul#list > li > img").hide();
    $("ul#list > li > img").eq(index-1).show()
})
```

Comment: Added questions.How do you like that case?

Comment: you want all second images to load? or what

Answer (score 0):

I have posted the sample in the codepen please check with this option.

```
[view on codepen][1]


  [1]: http://codepen.io/satheeshmallow/pen/xEBpEr
```

[Worked Example](http://codepen.io/satheeshmallow/pen/xEBpEr)

Answer (score 0):

I made your requirement with adding class and removing class,

it will help you to achieve some what,

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-1st" class="first-img" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-2nd" class="second-img" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-3er" class="third-img" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-1st" class="first-img" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-2nd" class="second-img" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-3er" class="third-img" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-1st" class="first-img" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-2nd" class="second-img" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-3er" class="third-img" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-1st" class="first-img" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-2nd" class="second-img" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-3er" class="third-img" />
    </li>
</ul>
<button id="showImage1">
Show Image 1
</button>
<button id="showImage2">
Show Image 2
</button>
<button id="showImage3">
Show Image 3
</button>
<button id="showAll">
Show All
</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
img {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
.display-none{
  display:none;
}
.display-inline{
  display:inline;
}
```

**JS:**

$("body").on('click','#showImage1', function(){debugger;
$(".first-img").addClass('display-inline').removeClass('display-none');
$(".second-img,.third-img").addClass('display-none').removeClass('display-inline');
});

```
$("body").on('click','#showImage2', function(){debugger;
$(".second-img").addClass('display-inline').removeClass('display-none');
$(".first-img,.third-img").addClass('display-none').removeClass('display-inline');
});

$("body").on('click','#showImage3', function(){debugger;
$(".third-img").addClass('display-inline').removeClass('display-none');
$(".first-img,.second-img").addClass('display-none').removeClass('display-inline');
});

$("body").on('click','#showAll', function(){
$(".first-img,.second-img,.third-img").addClass('display-inline').removeClass('display-none');
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/C3szT/113/)

Answer (score -1):

Let me know if you like this:

JS(with JQuery) / CSS / HTML

```js
$("button").click(function(){
 $(".first-img").removeClass("selected");
  $(".second-img").removeClass("selected");
  $(".third-img").removeClass("selected");
  $("." + $(this).attr("data-item-class")).addClass("selected");
});
```

```css
ol,
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
}
.slider {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 980px;
}
img.first-img,
img.second-img,
img.third-img {
  display:none;
}

.selected{
  max-height: 625px;
  display:block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-item-class="first-img">Class 1 </button>
<button data-item-class="second-img">Class 2 </button>
<button data-item-class="third-img">Class 3 </button>

<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-1st" class="first-img selected" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-2nd" class="second-img" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-3er" class="third-img" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-1st" class="first-img selected" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-2nd" class="second-img" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-3er" class="third-img" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-1st" class="first-img selected" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-2nd" class="second-img" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-3er" class="third-img" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-1st" class="first-img selected" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-2nd" class="second-img" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/980x625/?text=image-3er" class="third-img" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Or fiddle if you like it better https://jsfiddle.net/fart52wL/1/

Also if you don't like using IDs you can use classes for selectors.

[Edit] updates snipped and fiddle

Comment: Thank you.Added content in question.How do you change?
http://codepen.io/soso77/pen/bwkYZX

Comment: Let me see if i get this right.. you want all the images with class1 to become visible when you press the button 1, all the images with class 2 to become visible when you press button 2, etc.. ? Updated snippet and fiddle